# jfrog cli get just the names of artifacts?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

```
jfrog rt s "repo/some.pacakge.name*"
```

Gives me a list of big json objects for each artifact. I just want one line returned for each one, ideally just specific properties for each one (like just the name and version). is this possible? Didnt see anything in the docs.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, I want the CLI to get only the artifacts names. e.g. ["one", "artifact2", "other"] But instead a get a big object.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the result and do any manipulation on it.
A good example could be using jq.

jfrog rt s "repo/some.pacakge.name*" | jq '.[]|.path + .props["version"]' -r

You will have to install jq

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/